# Check if object has all the keys with value as empty array

Tags: javascript

I need to apply extra discount if there is no item to be added or excluded.

`applyDiscount()` accepts `item` and if there is no item passed it sets default value.

Same goes for `excludeItem`.

So, if there is no `spares`, `others`, `labours` and `services` and also there is no item to be excluded  in `orderItems` and `extraWorks`, It should apply `extra_discount`

This is what I tried,

```js
function applyDiscount({
  item = {
    spares: [],
    others: [],
    labours: [],
    services: [],
  },
  order_id,
  excludeItem = {
    extraWorks: [],
    orderItems: [],
  },
  extra_discount,
}) {
if (
  !(excludeItem.extraWorks.length 
  && excludeItem.orderItems.length
  && item.spares.length 
  && item.others.length 
  && item.labours.length 
  && item.services.length)
  ) {
  console.log('Applied Extra Discount')
}
  }

applyDiscount({});
```

Above works fine.

But If add any `spares` or any of `extraWorks` or `orderItems` is empty even it applies extra discount.

```js
function applyDiscount({
  item = {
    spares: ['spare1',],
    others: [],
    labours: [],
    services: [],
  },
  order_id,
  excludeItem = {
    extraWorks: [],
    orderItems: [],
  },
  extra_discount,
}) {
if (
  !(excludeItem.extraWorks.length 
  && excludeItem.orderItems.length
  && item.spares.length 
  && item.others.length 
  && item.labours.length 
  && item.services.length)
  ) {
  console.log('Applied Extra Discount')
}
  }

applyDiscount({});
```

While it should only apply `extra_discount` if `item` is not there or all the keys in item is empty array and `excludeItem` is not there or it has all the keys as empty array.

How can I make sure here that `item` has all the keys as empty array and also the `excludeItem`?

Comment: It's very difficult to parse and understand your question.

Comment: @jarmod I updated the question please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really **all** of the properites of those objects, you could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of the property values and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to see if they're all empty. Utility function:

```
function allEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).every(val => val.length === 0);
}
```

Then:

```
if (allEmpty(excludeItem) && allEmpty(item)) {
  console.log('Applied Extra Discount')
}
```

Updated Snippet:

```js
function allEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).every(val => val.length === 0);
}
function applyDiscount({
  item = {
    spares: [],
    others: [],
    labours: [],
    services: [],
  },
  order_id,
  excludeItem = {
    extraWorks: [],
    orderItems: [],
  },
  extra_discount,
}) {
if (
  allEmpty(excludeItem)
  && allEmpty(item)
  ) {
  console.log('Applied Extra Discount')
}
  }

applyDiscount({});
```

Comment: I had to change `allEmpty(excludeItem.extraWorks)` to `allEmpty(excludeItem`)

Comment: @confusedWarrior - Gah! Of course. :-) Typo. Glad that helped!